# How to move gameobject in unity test

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

here is my [full code](https://github.com/roroco/Test.Unity.Test)
following is my test code:

```
[UnityTest]
public IEnumerator NewPlayModeTest1WithEnumeratorPasses()
{
    // Use the Assert class to test conditions.
    // yield to skip a frame
    var c = GameObject.Find("Cube");
    c.transform.Translate(new Vector3(100, 100, 100));
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    Assert.True(true);
}
```

I hope move gameobject in unity test, but when i run test, nothing happen

[image]

and raise following err:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
NewPlayModeTest+<NewPlayModeTest1WithEnumeratorPasses>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at Assets/Script/NewPlayModeTest.cs:22)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
```

so how to move object in unity test

Comment: Did you looked over there? [Moving the Player](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial/moving-player) - [Positioning GameObjects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html)
 - [Creating Player Movement (Single Player)](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/creating-player-movement-single-player)

Comment: @Hille I can move object in unity monobehaviour, in this question, I hope move object in unity test, but it raise error

Comment: To my knowledge, you cannot use Update() without implementing Monobehaviour, which is what Transform.Translate() uses. So, the first thing I'd do is set it's .position property manually. But, the error is that the test isn't finding the "Cube" object.. I noticed in your picture that the "Cube" object disappears from the scene hierarchy when you are testing. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it, as I have never used the testing tools.

Comment: One thing you could try is giving the cube a "tag" and doing a GameObject.FindWithTag(), and then Debug.Log(go.name) just to see if maybe the testing is caching the name as some weird string.. That could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can just load a scene in the tests by writing the following:

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("MainScene");
    Debug.Log("Loaded Main Scene");
}
```

And then you don't need to create any test objects, especially if you use references from the Inspector.

Answer (score -4):

I figured out that when I run the test script, the unity editor will create a new scene for test. So in the new scene, my old scene gameobject cannot be found.

I figured out a solution. From the old scene, drag the object to file explorer, which will init a obj.prefab.  Then in the test script, load this prefab for testing.

Comment: This should be a comment on your initial post, not an answer.